# Laravel 8 Manually Authenticating Users does not persist the session

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-8

I would like to manually authenticating the user in a simple way, but I can't persist the session between routes.

I've made a fresh new installation of **Laravel 8** with **Laravel breeze**, after configuring breeze I can create a user and log in with the user through the breeze login screen, but if I try to **manually** create a session for the user (skipping the user pass check), the session is not persisted

To test: I go first to /manual where the user is authenticated then I check the session going on the route /tes. But no session/cookie are registered in the browser!!!

This is the router

```php
  Route::get('/test', [TestController::class, 'testSession']);
  Route::get('/manual', [TestController::class, 'manualLogin']);
```

This is the controller

```php
 class TestController extends Controller
 {

    public function testSession(Request $request)
    {
        dump(Auth::user());
    }

    public function manualLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::where('id', 3)->first();
        Auth::login($user, true);
        dump(Auth::user());
    }
```

This are the route with the **web** middleware group:

```
+----------+---------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Method   | URI                             | Action                                                | Middleware   |
+----------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GET|HEAD | manual                          | App\Http\Controllers\TestController@manualLogin       | web          |
| GET|HEAD | test                            | App\Http\Controllers\TestController@testSession       | web          |
+----------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And this is the middleware group app/Http/Kernel.php

```php
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
//            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];
```

I am missing something but what?

edit:added middleware info

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your session is persisted between your http calls ?

if not :

Check that your storage/ folder have the correct right

Make sure the SESSION_DRIVER variable is NOT null

Try to switch between 'encrypt' => false, and 'encrypt' => true,

Try to switch between 'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false), and 'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', true),

Comment: I am sure session does work , I've installed laravel jetstream and it comes with user registration and login. In fact I registered the user via user registration and I am able to log in.
Those two routes are outside the built in authentication with auth:sanctum

Comment: Are you sure route route have the middleware startsession ?

Comment: yes the Middleware\StartSession is part of the web group that is attached to the route

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found out the issue: everything was working fine but since I was dumping the $user to inspect the result, the session cookies where not passed to the browser because the headers were already set. See Response->sendHeaders() called by response->send()

```php
/**
* Sends HTTP headers.
*
* @return $this
*/
public function sendHeaders(){
    // headers have already been sent by the developer
    if (headers_sent()) {
        return $this;
    }
}
```